# Laravel POST Request does not work when textarea value has iframe

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 7. When the value of my textarea is following, the POST request does not work.

```
<p>Some text</p>
<p><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/R40rzI5QMjc" width="560" height="314"></iframe></p>
```

When the form is submitted it simply reloads the page. In the browser's console, I can see it returns the following

```
[HTTP/2 403 Forbidden 1613ms]
```

However, without the iframe tag in the textarea, it works perfectly

Could you please give me an idea of what could be the issue?

Comment: That likely doesn’t have anything to do with laravel, but with some security module/extension installed on the web server.

Comment: @CBroe you are probably right. Because it works on my local but does not work on live server. Do you have any idea which module could it be?

Comment: Suhosin or ModSecurity would be some of the “usual suspects” I can think of. But if you don’t know, you should best ask your hoster.